# PHP - Sort array of images by height

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Taking the following;

```
// Looping through images passed to function...

list($width[$i], $height[$i]) = getimagesize($img_urls[$i]);

// ... Now to reorder by height
```

How can I reorder the `$height` array to tallest > shortest, while maintaining the key relationship with the correct `$width` value?

I've attempted with `uasort`, but I've had no luck. The "closest" attempt I've had is below, but that sorts from smallest to largest

```
uasort($height, function($a, $b) use ($i) {
    return $a[$i] + $b[$i];
});
```

Comment: PLease code your sorting attempts so that we can see what your problem is. `uasort` is the way to go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, use structures:

```
class Image {
    public $width;
    public $height;
}
```

This is neccessary because width and heights of the image are hardly connected. Width of one image shows nothing without height of image. Same for height. You should link this data. For example, in structure.

After that, get images heights and widths:

```
$images = array();

// get widths and heights
loop start
    $img = new Image();
    $img->width = assign width;
    $img->height = assign height;
    $images[] = $img;
loop end
```

Finally, sort:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a->height == $b->height) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->height < $b->height) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($images, 'cmp');

//$images are sorted by height now
```

Let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$images = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($img_urls); $i++) {
    $image_size = getimagesize($img_urls[$i]);
    $images[$image_size[1]]['width'] = $image_size[0];
    $images[$image_size[1]]['height'] = $image_size[1];
}
sort($images);
var_dump($images);
```

Answer (score -1):

uasort should work fine:

```
uasort( $height, function ( $a, $b ) { if ( $a == 0 ) { return 0; } else { return ( $a > $b ) ? -1 : 1; } } );
```

If I do this:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = 512;
$arr[1] = 1024;
uasort( $arr, function ( $a, $b ) { if ( $a == 0 ) { return 0; } else { return ( $a > $b ) ? -1 : 1; } } );
var_dump( $arr );
var_dump( $arr[0] );
var_dump( $arr[1] );
```

I get:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  int(1024)
  [0]=>
  int(512)
}
int(512)
int(1024)
```

Comment: -1. Now connection `width-height` is lost.

Comment: Um, it keeps the same keys while reordering the array.

Comment: So provide full answer and tell about it. I don't think current answer can help.

Comment: There's not much more to say. The question says they had no luck with uasort but it should be working fine.

Comment: The question is: `PHP - Sort array of images by height`, but not `PHP - Sort array by uasort() function` now works`. But as you wish.